# Close VB.Net form without message box if textboxes are empty

Tags: vb.net

I am currently trying to fix the form closing event in VB.Net so that when there is text in txtInput1 and txtInput2 when the user tries to exit the form it will exit with a warning prompt from the message box. This works, however it should not show this prompt if there is nothing in either box, the form should just close. Here is the form close event i have so far, but it is not working:

```
 'FormClosing Event
Private Sub MyForm_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing


    If (txtInput1.Text = "" And txtInput2.Text = "") Then

        Me.Close()
    End If

    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you sure you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: _ but it is not working_ - How you know this is not working?

Comment: Would this result in a recursion? since when you call `Me.Close()`, the `Form_Closing` event will be fired. ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't call `Close` in the `FormClosing` event handler. If that event is raised then the form is already closing UNLESS you specifically prevent it, i.e. unless you set `e.Cancel` to `True`.

As for the issue, if you want to display the message ONLY IF a certain condition is true then it should be obvious that the code that displays it must be inside an `If` block.  Think about what it is you want to do and do that. Write it down if you need to, so you have something to actually compare your code to. You want to display the message if only one `TextBox` is empty, so that's what you need to test for and do:

```
If (txtInput1.Text = String.Empty AndAlso txtInput2.Text <> String.Empty) OrElse
   (txtInput1.Text <> String.Empty AndAlso txtInput2.Text = String.Empty) Then
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you sure you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End If
```

If you think a bit harder about the condition then you can simplify that code somewhat.  If you create a list of the `Text` values from the `TextBoxes` then you only want to display the message if that list contains one empty `String`:

```
If {txtInput1.Text, txtInput2.Text}.Count(Function(s) s = String.Empty) = 1 Then
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you sure you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End If
```